# Is there more concise way to write code with NaN condition in dart?

Tags: dart

The cord I am in need is below:

```dart
//These two variables are double and both can be 0.0, so the result can be NaN.
(data['amount'] / totalSpending).isNaN ? 0.0 : (data['amount'] / totalSpending)
```

The equivalent can be achieved in Javascript, like this

```js
data['amount'] / totalSpending || 0.0
```

I want to do same thing in Dart, but the `||` operator doesn't seem to allow other than type boolean in Dart. Do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in way, but you could do:

```dart
extension DefaultNaN on double {
  double defaultIfNaN(double value) => isNaN ? value : this;
}
```

and then you could do `(data['amount'] / totalSpending).defaultIfNaN(0)`.

You can't override `||` since `||` has special short-circuiting behavior, but you alternatively could override `|` for `double`:

```dart
extension DefaultNaN on double {
  double operator |(double value) => isNaN ? value : this;
}
```

and then you could do `data['amount'] / totalSpending | 0`.  However, I don't necessarily recommend that since I personally don't think that (or even JavaScript's `||` usage) is very readable, and if someone reading the code isn't already familiar with it, it's hard to search for.